# SED White Space replacement only between variables, regex usage

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sorting, sed

i recently came across a tricky situation while doing log analysis, am not an expert in REGEX so just wanted to post here and see if i get any good solution

**problem:** Below i have pasted the result that i got by performing awk and grep command on a unix log file. using **awk |sort |uniq -c**

```
          `2851 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=17`
          `2851 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=17`
          `1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=10`
          `1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=20`
          `1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=20`
           `248 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=8`
           `248 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=8`
           `236 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=7`
           `127 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=16`
           `127 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=16`
            `67 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=1`
```

I piped this above output ("|") and applied sed command to it to sort 7th feild (i.e RMC values in descending order), so i used this

**sed's/=/ / g' |sort -rnk 7,7** .

After sorting the value i again changed the out to look like previous, so i re-applied the sed i used,

**sed 's/=/ / g' |sort -rnk 7,7 |sed 's/ /=/g'**

This is what i was expecting

```
       `1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=20`
       `1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=20`
       `2851 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=17`
       `2851 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=17`
        `127 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=16`
        `127 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=16`
       `1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=10`
        `248 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=8`
        `248 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=8`
        `236 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=7`
         `67 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=1`
```

but my output looks something like this

```
    `===1323=ABC=10087=ACG=123=RMC=20`
    `===1323=ABC=10087=ACG=123=RMC=20`
    `===2851=ABC=10087=ACG=123=RMC=17`
    `===2851=ABC=10087=ACG=123=RMC=17`
    `====127=ABC=10087=ACG=123=RMC=16`
    `====127=ABC=10087=ACG=123=RMC=16`
    `===1323=ABC=10087=ACG=123=RMC=10`
    `====248=ABC=10087=ACG=123=RMC=8`
    `====248=ABC=10087=ACG=123=RMC=8`
    `====236=ABC=10087=ACG=123=RMC=7`
    `=====67=ABC=10087=ACG=123=RMC=1`
```

How can i achieve my desired output ?

Comment: It looks like you can use `... | sort -rnk4.6` on your input.

Answer (score 2):

You only need sort with -t option :

```
sort -t = -rnk 4
```

If you tell sort to take the equal sign as the field-seperator it works.

Answer (score 2):

Why *sed* if you can do this?

```
echo "$response" | sort -t '=' -nr -k4
1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=20
1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=20
2851 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=17
2851 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=17
127 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=16
127 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=16
1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=10
248 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=8
248 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=8
236 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=7
67 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=1
```

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I got rid of the backticks cause that was messing me up. You could try

```
$ echo "2851 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=17
2851 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=17
1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=10
1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=20
1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=20
248 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=8
248 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=8
236 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=7
127 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=16
127 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=16
67 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=1"| sed 's/=/ / g' |sort -rnk 7,7| sed -e 's/ /=/2' -e 's/ /=/3' -e 's/ /=/4'
```

Which gives me

```
1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=20
1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=20
2851 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=17
2851 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=17
127 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=16
127 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=16
1323 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=10
248 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=8
248 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=8
236 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=7
67 ABC=10087 ACG=123 RMC=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your last `sed` change every blank space to `=`. Instead, try

```
sed 's/=/ / g' |sort -rnk 7,7 |sed 's/RMC /RMC=/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*=\(.*\)/\1\t&/' file |
sort -nr |
sed 's/.*\t//'
```

Add the key(s) to be sorted to the start of the line, sort, remove the key(s).

In this case, however, the answers by  Matias Barrios and Oliver Gaida are sufficient.